# WordPress Ignoring 301 Redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have recently started using Wordpress for building sites rather than Joomla but appear to be having difficulty in re-directing old URL's to the new URL.

I have a lot of URL's to re-direct so I use an online 301 generator which has always worked perfectly for me in Joomla but WordPress just ignores it.

Any idea's where I am going wrong.

Here is a snippet of my .htaccess.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# 301 Redirect 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^cm\xE2\x80\x8E/$ /? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# 301 Redirect 2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^cm/commercial\.html\xE2\x80\x8E$ /commercial-solicitors? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# 301 Redirect 3
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^cm/insolvency\.html\xE2\x80\x8E$ /commercial-solicitors/insolvency-service/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# 301 Redirect 4
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^cm/court-work\.html\xE2\x80\x8E$ /court-work/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# 301 Redirect 5
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^cm/renting-properties\.html$ /property/leasing-properties/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]`
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your own rules above WordPress' one.

The `[L]` (last) flag on some of WordPress' rules tells it to ignore subsequent rules.

In other words, place them above `# BEGIN WordPress`

Comment: I have found the issue.

For some reason the generator was adding \xE2\x80\x8E to the end of eevry URL. I took this out and it works.